Kotlin Coroutines based Spring EL Evaluation failed
Given an interface and an implementation class like this.
interface MyBean{
   suspend fun suspend isEnabled(name:String): Boolean
}

@Service("myBean")
@NoArg // I created an annotation and configured the noarg plugin 
//to satisfy Spring EL's `noarg default constructor` requirements.
class MyMbean(val antoherBean: AnotherBean): MyBean{

   override suspend fun isEnabled(name:String): Boolean{
   }
}


When applied it on the @ConditonalOnExpression like this.
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnExpression("#myBean.isEnabled('test')")
class MyConfig{}


For the EL string, I have tried #{myBean.isEnabled('test')} etc. None worked.
EL1008E: Property or field 'myBean' cannot be found on object of type 
'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext'
 - maybe not public or not valid?

I was using the latest Spring Boot 3.3.1 and Kotlin 2.0.0/Kotlin Coroutines 1.8.x.
Update: I have tried to remove the suspend modifier but still encountered failure.

Executing a suspend function requires being in the coroutine context and generally having their support. I doubt Spring does this for @ConditionalOnExpression. If this is something simple like reading from a file, etc., I suggest creating another function that wraps the first in runBlocking. This is the easiest to do and shouldn't cause problems.

I have tried to remove suspend in a simple example, got the same result.

We normally use @Configuration annotation as place where "core" beans has been defined.
And then use @Component (or @Service, @Repository) annotation  to define "specific" beans which use "core" beans.
That why MyConfig class will be init before MyMbean class.
If you want to try do that. I suggest 2 solution:
Solution 1
Make MyConfig depends on myBean and move @ConditionalOnExpression on creating bean method:
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnBean(name = "myBean")
public class MyConfig {

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnExpression("@myBean.isEnabled('test')")
    public String simpleBean() {
        return "simpleBean";
    }
}

Note: use @ to get bean references
Solution 2
You have to customize own condition and create bean manually:
@Configuration
@Conditional(MyBeanCondition.class)
public class MyConfig {}

public class MyBeanCondition implements ConfigurationCondition {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        MyMbean mybean = context.getBeanFactory().createBean(MyMbean.class);
        return mybean.isEnabled("test");
    }

    @Override
    public ConfigurationPhase getConfigurationPhase() {
        return ConfigurationPhase.REGISTER_BEAN;
    }
}

